# NSPopover crashes on segue triggered programmatically, OSX, Xcode 8.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a simple setup (OSX not iOS):
Two windows A and B. Window A is a splash screen, window B the main screen.

Flow is like this -> Window A on app start, opens window B on "New Project" button click.

Window B contains a button. Button is setup in IB to open a view within a popover (via segue). Segue on button click works as expected.
On some place i trigger that segue programatically (performSegueWithIdentifier) to open the same popover attached to the button. This works as expected.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSHImportCSVPrefsViewController" sender:nil];
```

But: if i close window B which returns to window A and open window B again ("New project") the popover throws an error when triggered **programatically** even if the manual button click still works... im so confused...

```
[NSPopover showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:]: view has no window. You must supply a view in a window.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the whole code it turned out it was an observer not killed.
So when i closed window B and re-opened it, the same observer was created again, triggering the programmatically segue call twice, leading to the above described situation.

Solution: removeObserver on - (void)dealloc